# How do I slice an array using indices beyond the length of an array?

Tags: numpy

Suppose I have a 1d array `arr`. I want to slice this array at every nth element but beyond the normal array bounds. An example is below:

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(20)
n = 5
print(arr[0:n*20:n]) # not how it works just what I thought it would be like
#Desired output
#[0, 5, 10, 15, 0, 5, 10, 15, 0, 5, 10, 15, 0, 5, 10, 15, 0, 5, 10, 15]
#Actual output
#[0, 5, 10, 15]
```

How do I go beyond the regular bounds of the array such that the new index is basically just `index%arr.size`?

Comment: For both lists and arrays slices beyond the lenth are just ignored.  If you want wrap around try using `arange` followed by your modulus to get an array of indices.

Comment: @hpaulj the `arange` is not my use case unfortunately, also my example is kind of flawed because if you use a non divisible n (`length%n != 0` ) it's not the same elements repeating.

Comment: Could you update the question to reflect this requirement with a more realistic example? IIUC @hpaulj's approach seems to cover that as well: `arr[np.arange(0, 7*20, 7) % 20]`